# Linux. Одинаковые временные метки файла

Tags: linux

Почему если один процесс последовательно создаёт много файлов временные метки ctime,mtime будут одинаковые? Файловая система ext4. Создаю 100 файлов с помощью оболочки Bash. Получается как бы две группы файлов с одинаковыми timestamps. Почему? Что такое ctime,mtime на самом деле? То есть это момент чего, записи метаинформации файла?

```
for((i=0;i<100;++i))
do
    > "$i"
done
```

Смотрим вывод команды.

```
ls --full-time -lct
```

Тут даже ничего замерять не нужно. Очевидно что на каждой итерации. Манипуляции с  условием и телом цикла, занимают прилично времени. Плюс системный вызов `open*`. При этом вывод команды `ls` с наносекундной точностью, показывает несколько групп файлов с одинаковыми timestamps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392975/timestamp-accuracy-on-ext4-sub-millsecond Если коротко, то файловая система кэширует время в ядре и обновляет его значение по прерыванию таймера, поэтому файлы, созданные в пределах одного слота таймера будут иметь одинаковое время создания.

Comment: И добавить, что это не является проблемой.